# Configure a Vue Quasar CLI app so that a Cypress test launches the app in PWA mode?

Tags: vue.js, cypress, quasar-framework, quasar

I need my Cypress e2e test to run my Quasar app in pwa mode. By default, even if I have my quasar app running in pwa mode when I launch Cypress with the `yarn test:e2e` command, Cypress opens another instance of the app in spa mode.

For my specific purposes, this is an issue because the service worker that otherwise works without issue is never registered in the Cypress chrome instance during testing.

I've tried editing quasar.testing.json, which has a property that looked promising:

```
  "e2e-cypress": {
    "runnerCommand": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test start-test \"quasar dev\" http-get://localhost:9000 \"cypress run --e2e\""
  },
```

When I run `yarn test:e2e`, the output contains the value of the above `"runnerComand"`:

```
yarn test:e2e
yarn run v1.22.19
cross-env NODE_ENV=test start-test "quasar dev" http-get://localhost:9000 "cypress open --e2e"
1: starting server using command "quasar dev"
and when url "[ 'http-get://localhost:9000' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "cypress open --e2e"
```

However, when I make any edits to the value of the `"runnerCommand"`, the output does not change.
For example, I tried updating it to:

```
  "e2e-cypress": {
    "runnerCommand": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test start-test \"quasar dev -m pwa\" http-get://localhost:9000 \"cypress run --e2e\""
  },
```

But the output is still:

```
yarn test:e2e
yarn run v1.22.19
cross-env NODE_ENV=test start-test "quasar dev" http-get://localhost:9000 "cypress open --e2e"
1: starting server using command "quasar dev"
and when url "[ 'http-get://localhost:9000' ]" is responding with HTTP status code 200
running tests using command "cypress open --e2e"
```

If I delete the `"runnerCommand"` from quasar.testing.json, the test still runs and outputs the exact same! So it appears the actual configuration providing that string value is somewhere else somehow.

Unfortunately, [the official quasar-testing documentation](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-testing/blob/dev/packages/e2e-cypress/README.md) doesn't mention anything about how to run the Quasar app in different modes for Cypress testing.